# question about photodamage on plastic

Tags: photochemistry

I know that plastic are susceptible to UV attack. They create free radicals when put under sunlight even when kept for a short time.

I'd like to know if the photo-damage will stop once it is taken away from the sunlight or will it continue the photo-damage to the plastic. Does the rate becomes very slow because of the absence of light even when there is presence of free radicals?

Comment: What do you mean by "plastic".

Comment: Although radicals are involved this does not necessarily involve a chain propagation. The aging by UV should stop or slow down in absence of irradiation. Also, at least in term of viscosity, ,the eventually initiated process should be rather confined. In plastic items there will be the appropriate amount of scavengers so they should be more than effective in dark. Different is the case of an oil. Note that I am not a specialist by this is what I can think of.